# Angular 7: Extract a certain route name from the current route

Tags: angular, router, angular7

For instance if this Route is activated:

```
localhost/abc/xyz/:id/main
```

I want to know what is in place of main. Available options are  'main', 'feed', 'operations', 'associated', 'setting'.

it can be:

```
localhost/abc/xyz/:id/main
localhost/abc/xyz/:id/feed
localhost/abc/xyz/:id/operations
localhost/abc/xyz/:id/associated
localhost/abc/xyz/:id/setting
```

so whatever is written in the url at the last entry i want to capture that and use it in something.

Please mention the code to achieve this.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path parts with something like this:
`var segments = window.location.pathname.split('/');`

And then you are looking for the last one in the list: `segments[segments.length - 1]`